How to create a dynamic grid that changes column size when a subview's width changes in SwiftUI?
Let's say I have a grid with an image and text below it. There are 3 columns and 5 rows.
I want to refactor this to SwiftUI, and also add support for dynamic text sizing for accessibility.
The grid layout should have 3 columns by default, but changes to 2 columns when the text size gets bigger and 3 cells can't fit anymore, and to a single column when it gets even bigger.
What I tried so far:

I tried using LazyVGrid, with adaptive columns, column number doesn't change and the text just truncated.
I tried implementing a custom Layout, and achieved a Flow Layout, column number changes, but the sub views don't fill up the whole screen width. Some rows have 2 cells, some have 3:


This is what I am trying to achieve:


SwiftUI.Grid is likely the best option. But Layout can be adjust to whatever you want.

@loremipsum But aren't rows are pre-defined for Grid? I need to specifiy how many rows I want, and how many GridItem inside, which won't make them dynamic.

If all you are changing is the number of columns then the lazy grids do what you want just put the columns in a State and change the property based on whatever you want.

I am not changing columns myself, I want to find a way to change column numbers automatically when the dynamic font size setting changes and 3 cells can't fit in a row anymore.

.adaptive for the grid item is likely the “easiest” you’ll find. Everything else will require a lot more work because SwiftUI has no easy way of identifying the font size.

As I know, Lazy grid's .adaptive(_:) type works in the opposite direction: it adds more columns if the width of the screen got bigger and more columns can fit now. It doesn't care about the change of sub views' sizes.

You could use ViewThatFits and let it find the arrangement that works, starting with 3 columns, then 2, then 1:
struct ContentView: View {
    let labels = ["Text", "Longer Text", "Even Longer Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Text"]

    private func cellContent(label: String) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Text(label)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .fixedSize()
        }
    }

    private func gridForItems(nCols: Int) -> some View {
        let nRows = (labels.count / nCols) + (labels.count % nCols == 0 ? 0 : 1)
        return Grid {
            ForEach(0..<nRows, id: \.self) { row in
                GridRow {
                    ForEach(0..<nCols, id: \.self) { col in
                        let index = (row * nCols) + col
                        if index < labels.count {
                            cellContent(label: labels[index])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
                gridForItems(nCols: 3)
                gridForItems(nCols: 2)
                gridForItems(nCols: 1)
            }
//            .font(.largeTitle)
//            .font(.title)
            .font(.title2)
        }
    }
}


Thank you very much for your answer and time! I believe this is the correct approach, but I wish there was a cleaner way to do it, especially there are tools like Layout protocols that should achieve my goal.

Well yes, you can do it with Layout too. But as you have discovered, implementing a custom Layout is not always easy (and most of the attempts I have seen in SO are also far from clean). If you post the code you have tried already then it might be possible to help you to get it working.

Thought I had my day planned out on solving this problem.  Truly excellent solution and my day is free!
